# Automated test tools for Linux/ncurses

Tags: linux, integration-testing

I've picked up a legacy application developed in C/C++ on Linux, using ncurses for UI. What automated testing tools are there for this environment?

**Edit:** I've used AutomatedQA TestComplete in the past, and this is the type of tool I'm looking for - except running on Linux, and with the ability to test Text UI apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have considered using Rational Function Tester and TestComplete.

RFT has explicit support for testing this type of application (text-mode linux) via built-in terminal emulation.

TestComplete does not support testing Linux apps directly, but can be made to work by "testing" a COM-enabled terminal emulation program (Attachmate Reflection at this stage), and using COM from the test scripts to do screen scraping.

Have also considered using Reflection as the terminal emulator and rolling my own test framework in C# and NUnit.

Edit: "Final" solution is using Terminator (a Java terminal emulator), extending it with an RMI interface and using TestNG...

Answer (score 5):

I wrote something like that before. Not much docs, but you can try the code. It's written in Python and runs on Linux.

You would basically need the [ANSIterm filter](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/QA/pycopia/ANSIterm.py), and the [expect module](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/process/pycopia/expect.py). Then you compose them into a filter. You'll likely have to start the process with the [proctools](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/process/pycopia/proctools.py) module. They are all designed to work together or separately (modular).

Comment: I like this... if I'd seen it a month ago I might have gone this way. In the meantime, I've committed to using Java :-(

Comment: The project those links redirect to says it's Python 2 only

Answer (score 0):

The expect tool sounds like what you need: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: looks interesting. If only it could be combined with a terminal emulator so I could check resulting screen layouts...

Comment: Take a look at the term_expect demo of the expect distro. I think it does what you want.

Comment: I've had a really hard time finding the term_expect demo. The distro's I've looked at don't include it. I have read Don Libes papers about it however, and it looks like it's not up to doing the job I need. It provides a basic terminal emulator, whereas I need a full-featured emulator including colour information.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the free version of [TETware](http://tetworks.opengroup.org/) from the Open Group.  It is a full test harness based on TCL.

Comment: I looked at the website, looked at some of the docs, and I still don't understand what this actually does :-(