# How to debug a program that takes user input from stdin with GDB?

Tags: gdb

I have a program and I am trying to debug it using gdb. Inside the program I have methods that require the user to enter an input using stdin. How can I enter this input when I am in gdb? So that I can trace how my methods work?

Comment: For the simpler case of direct input, the question is the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455544 There are however cases which this does not cover: 1) you need to see stdout to decide stdin 2) actual timing and keypresses are needed like in ncurses. In those cases, maybe expect might do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579901/automated-test-tools-for-linux-ncurses

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$ cat >foo <<EOF
something
EOF
$ gdb -quiet /bin/cat
Reading symbols from /bin/cat...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install coreutils-8.12-7.fc16.x86_64
(gdb) run <foo
Starting program: /bin/cat <foo
something
[Inferior 1 (process 22436) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also run your program first, then attach GDB to it:

```
gdb --pid $(pgrep your_program)
```

This way you will be able to run your program interactively in a separate terminal.

Note: attaching GDB to another process might require using `sudo` or changing permissions.

Comment: how to run program first? I mean the executable compiled with `-g` flag is `a.out`. Should I run it using `a.out some parameters`. Then `gdb --pid <id>`? Or the `some parameters' will be entered in gdb?

Comment: I executed my file `./a.out 0 1 map1.txt`. I connect gdb just like I mentioned in previour comment. However, I was unable to debug the run executable.

Comment: Ok it require admin acces. I was able to connect it by using `sudo gdb ....`. Is there another way to make it possible without using `sudo`?

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171339/gdb-cannot-attach-to-process. But be wary that setting `ptrace_scope` to 0 has security implications as any process will be able to attach itself to another process.

Answer (score 3):

I just went through something like this yesterday and recursed through a bunch of "help" commands in gdb because I couldn't find exactly what I needed on the Internet.

I used `set variable *your_variable* = *your desired input*` after I had started gdb and began running my code.  Worked like a charm.

I know this is late, but maybe it'll help someone else.

Comment: How would you use this for stdin, though?