# Pass File Input and Stdin to gdb

Tags: linux, gdb

So I want to run a program in gdb with the contents of a file as an argument. Then, when an EOF is hit, I want to be able to enter user input again. For a normal program in a terminal I can do something like this with the following command.

```
(cat input.txt; cat) | ./program
```

In gdb I can pass in the file arguments like this, but it continues to enter newlines forever after the end of the file has been reached.

```
(gdb) run < input.txt
```

It is almost as if stdin was not passed back to the program, similar to what happens if I simply do

```
(cat input.txt) | ./program
```

without the second `cat`. Is this even possible to do in gdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the program in one console and attach to it with gdb from another one when it is waiting for input. Therefore you will be able to enter program input in the 1st console and debug it in the 2nd.

Comment: I have done this before. It does work, I was just wondering if it was possible to do it without 2 terminals. Is this a confirmation that it cannot be done entirely within gdb?

Comment: I guess you can also save user input to a second file and concatenate it with `input.txt` and do it entirely within gdb. Something like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13104206/72178.

Comment: That has the same issue I was having of not being able to take user input afterwards. Your answer works for me. I'm just going to accept it.