# gdb cannot attach to process

Tags: linux, docker, gdb, ptrace

Here is the OS I am using:

> Linux securecluster 4.9.8-moby #1 SMP Wed Feb 8 09:56:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When trying to attach gdb to hanging process as root user, I got the following:

```
Attaching to process 9636
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
```

I modified `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` ,resulting in:

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

However, I got the same error.
I tried changing /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope :

```
echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
tee: /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope: Read-only file system
```

Hint is appreciated.

Comment: In case you are in a docker container, try to re-enter it with `docker exec --privileged -ti <container> bash` and gdb should just work! See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328861/480898

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using a container engine?  Try attaching to the process from the outside of the container (on the host); it may have a different PID there.

Alternatively, launch the container with the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability (using `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE`, for example).  Of course, if you cannot reproduce the hang, then you cannot use this approach.

Comment: The environment is in docker. I couldn't find the process outside docker.

Comment: The process might have a different PID on the outside. Come to think of it, it may also help yo lift the YAMA ptrace restriction on the host (if it is enabled at all).

Comment: I use Docker on MacBook. Should the --cap-add flag be added in Dockerfile ?

Comment: No, it's an argument to `docker run`.

Comment: It's actually `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE`.

Answer (score 19):

> I modified /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

This will only take effect on next reboot.

Until then, just do `sudo sysctl -w kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0`

Comment: I tried that command: sysctl -w kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0
sysctl: setting key "kernel.yama.ptrace_scope": Read-only file system

Comment: @Ted did you find a solution to the Read-only file system issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Ted  @escapecharacter The kernel parameters you are referring to are taken from the host system that is why it is read-only, you cannot edit the actual config file from inside the container.  you can override it in the container, just drop the -w flag to #sudo sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0 . A permanent solution is to do this on the host node and all containers would inherit this by default.