# Shell scripting answering yes no dialog box automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, debian

I made a script to install some software, and automate the installation, I added a "-y" option to answer yes to questions during the installer but it only works when the user has to write the answer on the command line

When I am prompted via a dialog box (grey with blue background, like when installing macchanger) the "y" option does not work. This what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
apt-get install arista -y
apt-get install macchanger -y
```

The "-y" works with arista but when installing macchanger the installer just hangs at the blue screen waiting for me to select Yes or No and press Enter.

What do I write on the script file to give macchanger one of the two answers automatically without any prompts? The "-y" option does not work with the prompt given by macchanger.

Comment: That 'blue screen' is ncurses based. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579901 ...

Comment: What you should write is a bug report on the package that uses a curses based confirmation!

Comment: The question is is the package itself doing this or is this official package configuration. I would have expected that official package configuration would have honored `-y` so this is likely the package itself doing it, in which case as @WilliamPursell says, this is a bug in the package and should be filed as such.

Comment: Well, this happens with any package with a "blue screen" prompt, for example jackd2 does it as well, so I am inclined to think that it's the package configuration, however if no solution is to be found I could try and send a bug report to the developers of every package that I use that displays this problem.

Comment: anishsane I looked at the link and read the documentation for the Expect command, but I cannot understand how it's to be used, my knowledge of bash scripting is very limited, and even after extensive reading I am unable to use it properly. I'm not even sure if it could solve the problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @johnP.

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1143/848 and https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps

Answer (score -1):

You may try with this format,

```
apt-get -y install [packagename]
```

Comment: Sorry but it still hangs on the blue screen

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a pipe

```
yes '' | apt-get install macchanger
```

instead set a command-line option