# How to convert ncurses-based dialog to text-based?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, go

I am using the [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) utility *originally written by Savio Lam and later rewritten by Thomas E. Dickey* for several products.

I want to have any automation for them. So I tried to find any replacement of ncurses-based application to text-based (because text based I can parse) or any software that maight understand how to automate dialog-based solutions. But I failed to find.

Please advice.

Regards.

Comment: This can probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579901/automated-test-tools-for-linux-ncurses

Comment: There wasn't a solution

Comment: You should use have wrapper functions like `show_info(){ if [ -t 0 ] ; then dialog --msgbox "$*" 0 0; else echo "$@"; fi}`